# how to make the snake go beyond the screen, it will return to the other side of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

hey guys i just programmed the snake game but i want when x=0(my snake is in position 0) then immediately x=600 like it doesn't have a collision wall getting in its way,  how can i do it?

programming language: Python

the library i use is pygame

this is my code

```
import pygame, time

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#màu
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255,252,252)
red = (176, 59, 19)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake game by Vinhsieucapvjppro')

x = 300
y = 300
x_size = 10
y_size = 10
x1_change = 0       
y1_change = 0
vel = 5

game = True
while game:
    print(screen)
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,red,(x,y,x_size,y_size))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
    #di chuyển
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x1_change = -5
        y1_change = 0 
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x1_change = 5
        y1_change = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y1_change = -5
        x1_change = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y1_change = 5
        x1_change = 0

    x += x1_change
    y += y1_change
    if x == 0:  #<---- ở đây có lỗi
        x = 600
    if x == 600:
        x = 0
    if y == 0:  #<---- ở đây có lỗi
        y = 600 
    if y == 600:
        y = 0
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `%` (modulo) operator. The module operator computes the remainder of an integral division:

```py
x = (x + x1_change) % 600
y = (y + y1_change) % 600
```

---

The actual problem in your code is that you set `x = 600`, but you test `x == 600` on the following line

> ```
> if x == 0: 
>    x = 600
> if x == 600:
>    x = 0
> ```

If you want to implement it with conditions, you have to use `if`-`elif`:

```py
x += x1_change
y += y1_change

if x <= 0:
    x = 600
elif x >= 600:
    x = 0
    
if y <= 0:
    y = 600 
elif y >= 600:
    y = 0
```